# Default value to 'datetime' field in form loaded from the database

Tags: forms

I want to display the datetime field on my Drupal 8 form with some date loaded from the database, but the front end always shows empty fields as if no data has been provided. I tried several combinations to default_value field, but none of them are showing any thing.

The code I am using is the following.

```
$form['dateopening'] = array(
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Opening Date'),
  '#default_value'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateFromDB)),
);
```

Why doesn't it set the default value as expected?

Comment: add a format like : $format = 'Y-n-d'; then add default value like:
'#default_value' => date('c'),

Comment: It is 'datetime' field not 'date' field which I wanted. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The response is in this thread : [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257523/default-value-to-datetime-field-in-drupal-8-form-loaded-from-db)

```
$form['valid_dt'] = array(
    '#type' => 'datetime',
    '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp($data->valid_dt),
    '#title' => $this->t('Valid'),      
);
```